# Change Twig Content depending on existing session

Tags: symfony, dynamic, twig

Currently I am working on Symfony web-project. At the moment I have a `layout.html.twig` file that sets up a navigation bar and gets extended by any other `.html.twig` file.

Recently I implemented a user login area. Now I want to dynamically change the content of that navigation bar, depending of being logged in or not. Since I cannot directly write php code within a `.html.twig` file, I am not able to access the session variable.

What would be best practice to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so you want to login and at the same html-page you want to change the navbar without reloading the page?

Comment: you can access to session element in a twig template as `{% set filter = app.session.get('elem_name') %}`

Answer (score 0):

First send session variable through your controller to your html.twig:

```
public function mySiteAction(){
  $session = new Session();
  $yourVariable = $session->get('yourVariable');
  return array('sessionValue' => $yourVariable);
}
```

than you access it with twig like: 
mySite.html.twig

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="navbar">
        {{ sessionValue }}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

A shortcut for that procedure is

```
{% set element = app.session.get('elem_name') %}
```

For more informations -> see [Twig Documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html)
This solution presupposes, that you first login and go after that to a page where only logged in users can be.

Answer (score 0):

in twig you can check for the user state like

```
{% if app.user %}
  <div class="loggedInNav"></div>
{% else %}
  <div class="notLoggedInNav"></div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a specific variable from the controller the way Rubinum did, or you can access the user directly in twig like this.

```
{% if app.user %}
   # user is logged in
{% else %}
   # user is not logged in
{% endif %}
```

Comment: is that a shorter way to access values from authentificated users via the security thing in symfony? I learn more, everyday :D